# Run css animation to the end

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to create a favourite button using AngularJS. Essentially, I want it so that I can click on the gray heart and then there would be a .7 second animation. The animation would scale the button to 1.1x its size and then go back down to its original size but with red instead of gray. If you click on it again, it would do the same thing but change back to gray. The problem that I am running into is that if I use the class:active selector, if I don't hold the button for the entire .7 second, I would not be able to see the entire animation. If I use the ng-class method for this, I would only see the animation for changing the color from gray to red but not the other way around. Is there a way I can click on the favourite button (that can toggle) and see the entire .7 second animation without having to add a class to the button.

HTML (uses the ArticleCtrl controller below)

```
<a ng-click="like()" class="button button-icon heart" ng-class='{"liked":liked}'>
<i class="icon ion-heart"  ></i> {{numOfLikes}}</a>
```

CSS

```
.heart i {
   color: grey;
}

.liked {
   -webkit-animation-name: pop;
   -webkit-animation-duration:.7s;
   animation-name: pop;
   animation-duration: .7s;

}

@-webkit-keyframes pop {
  0% {

    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {

    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {

    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes pop {
  0% {

    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {

    transform: scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {

    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.liked i {
  color: red;
}
```

JS (angular)

```
function ArticleCtrl($s) {
  $s.numOfLikes = 45;

  $s.liked = false;
  $s.like = function() {
    if ($s.liked == false) {
      $s.liked = true;
      $s.numOfLikes += 1;
      console.log("Now True");
    } else {
      $s.liked = false;
      $s.numOfLikes -= 1;
      console.log("Now False");
    }
  }

angular.module("article",[])
.controller('ArticleCtrl',['$scope', ArticleCtrl])
```

Comment: Could you please share your HTML,CSS and JS code to debug easily?

Comment: Please add code for class="button button-icon" code